# jQuery youtube video update video

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I'm trying to change youtube video in real time but im getting nowhere;
In my code when I click first time the 'li' element the video loads correctly but if i try to click again the video isn't updating;
Here's my code:

```
function loadv(v)
  {
   var params = {
          allowScriptAccess: "always"
      };

      var atts = {
          id: "ytplayer1"
      };




    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/"+v+"?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer1",
                       "play", "480", "295", "9", null, null, params, atts);

  }


     $('#playlist li').click(function()
     {

           var video = $(this).attr('id');
           loadv( video );
           console.log(video); //shows the correct id

      });
```

And the html :

```
   <div id="play">You need Flash and JavaScript in order to view the video.</div>
    <div id="videoStatus">status</div>


       </br>
       <ul id="playlist">
     <li id="C0DPdy98e4c">1</li>
    <li id="zM0k99OpiXM">2</li>
    <li id="0ScsDReUTxw">3</li>
    <li id="crgB4TyzyXM">4</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the params when an object is created. But you can use **Youtube Javascript Player API** instead. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

The reference for the function you want (change the video in the generated player) is here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#loadVideoById